# Only allow 6 digit number as customer password

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-account, customer-attribute, password

Is there a way to make magento 2 only allow 6 digit number format as customer password?

Comment: Seem that it will be a security issue. The password is not strength.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh is there a way to bypass this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to customize the default password validation in customer registration form.

Navigate to

> app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Customer/templates/form/register.phtml

Find this line

```
data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-customer-password':true}"
```

and replace with this

```
data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-mycustom-password':true}"
```

Now add following code at the end of the file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        'jquery',
        'jquery/ui',
        'jquery/validate',
        'mage/translate'
    ], function($){
        $.validator.addMethod(
        'validate-mycustom-password', function (value) { 
        return (value.length == 6 && /^-?\d+$/.test(value));
        }, $.mage.__('Password length should be 6 and only numbers are allowed'));
    });
</script>
```

Also, change the minimum password length from

> Store > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration > Password
>   Options > Minimum Password length

Comment: @DineshYadev how to set allow number only?

Comment: @IdhamChoudry Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

No of characters can be restricted in below setting

> Store > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration > Password
>   Options > Minimum Password length.

To use numbers only, you have to extend the file and use `data-validate="{'validate-number':true}"` in the password element.

Answer (score 0):

Can't we simply change this directly in the template file like changing

```
<input name="login[password]" type="password" autocomplete="off" class="input-text" id="pass" title="Password" data-validate="{required:true}" aria-required="true">
```

into

```
<input name="login[password]" type="password" autocomplete="off" class="input-text" id="pass" title="Password" maxlength="6" pattern="\d{6}" data-validate="{required:true}" aria-required="true">
```

You can notice the use of **maxlength="6" pattern="\d{6}"** in the input box.

**pattern="\d{6}** would allow digit combination of 6 digits.

You will also need to set minimum characters in Magento admin to avoid conflict.